# What to do about this message that appears after sudo apt upgrade?

Tags: intel, unattended-upgrades

[image]

This message started appearing a few days ago when I do a sudo apt upgrade.
I'm on 23.10

Comment: This is an informational message only (see above) and nothing to worry about.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

Do nothing. Just read it, and go about your day. That isn't an error, it is just an informative message, letting you know that Canonical have issued fixes for two security vulnerabilities and that you might want to enable automatic (unattended) upgrades to always keep your system secure.